# My sqlite3 cursor has less rows than expected

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

In the following code I have two cursors the first loc_crs should have 3 rows in it. However when I run my program loc_crs seems to only have 1 row

```
import db_access

def get_average_measurements_for_area(area_id):
"""
Returns the average value of all measurements for all locations in the given area.
Returns None if there are no measurements.
"""
loc_crs = db_access.get_locations_for_area(area_id)

avg = 0
for loc_row in loc_crs:

    loc_id = int(loc_row['location_id'])
    meas_crs = db_access.get_measurements_for_location(loc_id)

    for meas_row in meas_crs:
        meas = float(meas_row['value'])
        avg += meas
        # print("meas: ", str(meas))

    print("loc_id: ", str(loc_id))
print(str(avg))
```

get_average_measurements_for_area(3)

This is my output.

```
loc_id:  16
avg:  568.2259127787871
```

EDIT: Here are the methods being called:

```
def get_locations_for_area(area_id):
"""
Return a list of dictionaries giving the locations for the given area.
"""
cmd = 'select * from location where location_area is ?'
crs.execute(cmd, [area_id])

return crs

def get_measurements_for_location(location_id):
"""
Return a list of dictionaries giving the measurement rows for the given location.
"""
cmd = 'select value from measurement where measurement_location is ?'
crs.execute(cmd, [location_id])
return crs
```

Here is a link to the database:
http://cs.kennesaw.edu/~bsetzer/4320su15/extra/databases/measurements/measures.sqlite

Comment: Without knowing what db_access does behind the screens, it'll be hard to tell what goes wrong. Can you make this into a standalone example that uses sqlite3 directly, without db_access (given an example database as well)? Basically an [ssce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The example given in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html#using-shortcut-methods) doesn't iterate over the cursor, it iterates over `cursor.execute`; hence, you may want to try and return `return crs.execute(cmd, [...])` instead. Or just use `return crs.fetchall()`.

Comment: @ Evert Edited. Is that better?

Comment: Thank you @Evert that solved my problem. Can you put that in an answer so I can say this question was answered?

Comment: One question on my side actually: do you now return `crs.execute`, or `crs.fetchall`? Cause I noticed later in the [next section in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html#accessing-columns-by-name-instead-of-by-index) that you can seemingly iterate through a cursor *after* having called `cursor.execute`.

Comment: I have multiple functions and the ones I need to iterate through I return crs.fetchall and the ones I don't need to iterate through I just return crs.execute. I'm not sure if that is the best solution but I was in a time crunch so I only changed what was necessary.